# В каком порядке читать книги по С#, .NET и другие необходимые книги для программиста?

Tags: c#, .net, книги

Меня интересует в каком порядке читать книги по С#, платформе .net и другие книги необходимые программисту после Шилдта, возможно что то параллельно. В каком порядке читать следующие книги?

- Эндрю Троелсен c# и платформа .net
- Гради Буч. Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование
- Банда Четырех. Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны    проектирования
- Мартин Фаулер. Рефакторинг. Улучшение существующего кода
- Стив Макконнел. Совершенный код
- Джеффри Рихтер clr via c#
- Петкович Д Microsoft SQL Server 2008. Руководство для начинающих

Comment: А какую конечную цель вы ставите? Выбирать, что читать надо, исходя из этого вопроса. Просто так что-то читать смысла нет.

Comment: написание desktop-приложений.

Answer (score 1):

Начать нужно с официального сайта по C#, там очень много полезностей! Ну и учиться, учиться, и ещё раз учиться!

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее про **официальный сайт C#.**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/
вот

Answer (score 1):

1. [Язык программирования C# 2010 и платформа .NET 4 Эндрю Троелсен](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5602592/)
2. [C#. Программирование для профессионалов Джон Скит](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7259035/)

Дальше пишите приложение по интересующей вас теме и поймете, что вам следует читать дальше и в каком порядке.

Answer (score 0):

По языку и платформе:

1. Троелсен
2. Джеффри Рихтер
3. Джон Скит

Перед прочтением монументального труда "Банды четырех", я бы советовал ознакомиться со следующей книгой по паттернам:

[Эрик Фримен](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31079082/)

Лучший способ чему-то научиться - начать кодить реальное приложение. Всю информацию из книг не запомните, а по мере разработки все равно будут появляться вопросы.